# If I install UP1, can I still use the JDBC stuff?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I know you can't mix UP1 and the Extension Library, but, can you still use the new JDBC datasources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the Extension Libray is open source, you could create an OSGi library that consists only of the JDBC data source features and install that atop UP1. That approach would allow you to use the "officially supported" version of everything else, treating only the JDBC data source as "use at your own risk".

Comment: Thanks Tim. We have always been a Notes Client shop and have no web apps, so,as we go through all this, we are having to learn all the ins and outs of setting up our servers to run Xpages.  On top of that, we are government contractor, so, we have lots of security issues to work through as well.  It's been an interesting journey so far and the folks on this site have been a tremendous help. Thanks again.